# SSIS If String Isn't Present, Redirect Records

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, ssis

I'm using SSIS 2008 R2 and I'm trying to figure out the right components to check if one of two strings are present within a string. If so a boolean value should be assigned. If neither are present, the package should redirect the records to a different component.

I've tried using a derived column to do this but am struggling to check for two strings. So far I've used the expression:

```
(FINDSTRING(fixed_notes,"no answer",1) > 0) ? (DT_BOOL) FALSE : (DT_BOOL) TRUE
```

This will not do though as I need to assign `TRUE` if `fixed_notes` contains `answered`, `False` if `fixed_notes` contains `no answer` and finally redirect any records that contain neither `answered` or `no answer`.

Could anyone help with how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried the conditional split?

Comment: @NeilP I've had a look but how can I manipulate a new column with a boolean value based on the outcome? Thanks

Comment: I think I've got it actually by splitting the records then using two different destinations to write the records